# Find and replace words in XML string

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I have a string with XML content, which basically has the configurations required to execute the test script.

`$SUB_SEND`, `$COUNTRY_CODE`, `$DOMAIN` are all read from a config file.

```
<Provisioning xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Request><Header><Command>Create</Command><EntityIdentifiers><Identifier Type="TelephoneNumber" Value="$SUB_SEND"/></EntityIdentifiers><EntityName>Subscriber</EntityName></Header><Data><Subscriber><!--<RcvMaxMmsMsgSize>53</RcvMaxMmsMsgSize>--><OperatorCode>54</OperatorCode><SendAutoReply>0</SendAutoReply><CopyReceivedMessagesEnabled>0</CopyReceivedMessagesEnabled><RequestMmsDeliveryReport>1</RequestMmsDeliveryReport><CopySentMessagesEnabled>0</CopySentMessagesEnabled><SendMmsToMbx>0</SendMmsToMbx><AddSignature>0</AddSignature><SubscriberCosName>Standard MMS</SubscriberCosName><!--<SendMmsMaxAttachNum>50</SendMmsMaxAttachNum>--><!--<SendMmsMaxRcptNum>51</SendMmsMaxRcptNum>--><!--<HandsetType>LegacyPhone</HandsetType>--><SubscriberDomainName>$DOMAIN</SubscriberDomainName><AutoProvIndication>1</AutoProvIndication><!--<SendMaxMmsMsgSize>52</SendMaxMmsMsgSize>--><MmsUserType>None</MmsUserType><BWListInUse>None</BWListInUse><AllowMmsDeliveryReport>1</AllowMmsDeliveryReport><!--<BillingType>PrePaid</BillingType>--><CountryCode>**$COUNTRY_CODE**</CountryCode><SubscriberName>$SUB_SEND</SubscriberName></Subscriber></Data></Request></Provisioning>
```

Now I need a read each line and find the occurrence of words beginning with `$` and replace it with config file.
How can I get all the words beginning with `$` in VBScript?

Comment: If you have this in a string just use `myXmlString = Replace(myXmlString, "$SUB_SEND", "MyValueFromConfig")` and repeat for `$COUNTRY_CODE` and `$DOMAIN`

Comment: let me add some more points. I don't want to hard code it and i want read all words beginning with $ and save it in string and replace it with config values. So that solution will be more generic and if someone adds more config elements and don't need add more lines for replace.

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not a free code-writing service. Also, where do the values you want to substitute come from?

Comment: I tried with hard coded values in the Replace as the required got changed it should handle dynamic values from config file. I'm writing by Spit on xmlLine on "$", since the config name are not of same format the text is appended with extra characters.

Comment: Please post the code in your original post so that we can understand your problem and help in a better way

Comment: Again, where do these dynamic values come from and how do you intend to map them to the placeholders?

Comment: These values are read from UFT config file. Environment.value()

Answer (score 1):

If you really can treat your .xml as plain ASCII text, use a [regexp replace function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974619.aspx#scripting12_topic1) and a Dictionary for the data:

```
Option Explicit

' path to src file
Const p = "e:\work\proj\soa\tmp\45371693.xml"

Dim s : s = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(p).ReadAll()

' Regexp to find $ + Seq of Alphas or _
Dim r : Set r = New RegExp
r.Global = True
r.Pattern = "\$[A-Z_]+"

' Find/Replace pairs in a dictionary
Dim d : Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
d("$SUB_SEND") = "Abra"
d("$DOMAIN") = "cada"
d("$COUNTRY_CODE") = "bra"

' RegExp replace using function f
s = r.Replace(s, GetRef("f"))

WScript.Echo s

WScript.Quit 0

' replace found $X with d($X)
Function f(m, p, s)
  If d.Exists(m) Then m = d(m)
  f = m
End Function
```

output:

```
cscript 45371693-2.vbs
<Provisioning xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Request>
                <Header>
                        <Command>Create</Command>
                        <EntityIdentifiers>
                                <Identifier Type="TelephoneNumber" Value="Abra"/>
                        </EntityIdentifiers>
                        <EntityName>Subscriber</EntityName>
                </Header>
                <Data>
                        <Subscriber>
                                <!--<RcvMaxMmsMsgSize>53</RcvMaxMmsMsgSize>-->
                                <OperatorCode>54</OperatorCode>
                                <SendAutoReply>0</SendAutoReply>
                                <CopyReceivedMessagesEnabled>0</CopyReceivedMessagesEnabled>
                                <RequestMmsDeliveryReport>1</RequestMmsDeliveryReport>
                                <CopySentMessagesEnabled>0</CopySentMessagesEnabled>
                                <SendMmsToMbx>0</SendMmsToMbx>
                                <AddSignature>0</AddSignature>
                                <SubscriberCosName>Standard MMS</SubscriberCosName>
                                <!--<SendMmsMaxAttachNum>50</SendMmsMaxAttachNum>-->
                                <!--<SendMmsMaxRcptNum>51</SendMmsMaxRcptNum>-->
                                <!--<HandsetType>LegacyPhone</HandsetType>-->
                                <SubscriberDomainName>cada</SubscriberDomainName>
                                <AutoProvIndication>1</AutoProvIndication>
                                <!--<SendMaxMmsMsgSize>52</SendMaxMmsMsgSize>-->
                                <MmsUserType>None</MmsUserType>
                                <BWListInUse>None</BWListInUse>
                                <AllowMmsDeliveryReport>1</AllowMmsDeliveryReport>
                                <!--<BillingType>PrePaid</BillingType>-->
                                <CountryCode>**bra**</CountryCode>
                                <SubscriberName>Abra</SubscriberName>
                        </Subscriber>
                </Data>
        </Request>
</Provisioning>
```